# Reference a button outside of a loop?

Tags: c#, winforms, button

This function dynamically creates nine buttons for use in a game I am making. You can see what attributes I give to the button.

```
private void createbuttons()
{
    int tot = 0;
    int x = 100;
    int y = 100;

    while(tot < 9)
    {
        string buttonsname = (tot + "button").ToString();
        Button creating  = new Button();
        creating.Name = buttonsname;
        creating.Size = new Size(100, 100);
        creating.Click += delegate
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You clicked me!");
        };
        creating.Text = buttonsname;
        if(x > 300)
        {
            y += 100;
            x = 100;

        }
        creating.Location = new Point(x, y);

        Controls.Add(creating);
        tot += 1;
        x += 100;
    }

}
```

What I want to know is how to reference  these buttons in different parts of the same form. Specifically when 'Start Game' is clicked I want to change the text for each button to something different.

```
private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //What would I write here to change the text?
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form has a property `Controls` that holds all child controls. To find a child control by its `Name` property use method `Find`, which returns the array, because there may be several control with the same `Name`, but if you make sure that names exist, are unique, and you know their type (`Button`) you can just take the first item from the array and cast it:

```
private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button buttonNamedFred = (Button)this.Controls.Find("Fred", false)[0];

    buttonNamedFred.Text = "I'm Fred";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access the buttons by enumerating the controls, or you could create a list of buttons for future reference, and use that list later.

Here is how you do it with a list:

```
private IList<Button> addedButtons = new List<Button>();
private void createbuttons() {
    int tot = 0;
    int x = 100;
    int y = 100;

    while(tot < 9) {
        string buttonsname = (tot + "button").ToString();
        Button creating  = new Button();
        creating.Name = buttonsname;
        creating.Size = new Size(100, 100);
        creating.Click += delegate {
            MessageBox.Show("You clicked me!");
        };
        creating.Text = buttonsname;
        if(x > 300) {
            y += 100;
            x = 100;
        }
        creating.Location = new Point(x, y);
        addedButtons.Add(creating); // Save the button for future reference
        Controls.Add(creating);
        tot += 1;
        x += 100;
    }
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
foreach (var btn : addedButtons) {
    btn.Text = "Changed "+btn.Text;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought that I might have needed to add a list :)

Comment: The list (actually a `ControlCollection`) already exist. No need to maintain another one.

Comment: @Dialecticus Keeping buttons and other controls in separate collections outside the `Controls` collection saves you CPU cycles for larger forms, and may also improve readability of your code.